# extract digit from a string including minus sign python

Tags: python, regex, list, datetime

I have a multiple strings in a list such has `/Date(-31431600000)/`

I am trying to extract the digits including the minus sign and turning it back into a date. the string represent a linux EPOCH date

I tried:

```
import datetime as dt
date_list = ["/Date(-31431600000)/", "/Date(-31431600000)/"]
[dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), y)) / 1000) for y in date_list]`
```

but it misses the minus sign.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most safe regex here is:

```
(?:/Date\()(-?\d+)(?:\)/)
```

Since here you also check that it begins with `/Date(`, ends with `)/` and has only an optional minus sign in the front. You can then fetch dates with:

```
>>> import re
>>> rgx=re.compile(r'(?:/Date\()(-?\d+)(?:\)/)')
>>> rgx.match("/Date(-31431600000)/").group(1)
'-31431600000'
```

which is thus a string you can convert to an `int` with `int(..)`:

```
>>> int(rgx.match("/Date(-31431600000)/").group(1))
-31431600000
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?<=Date\()-\d+(?=\))
```

*see [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/TCUusH/2)*

**python** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/pdW6kN) )

```
import re
regex = r"(?<=Date\()-\d+(?=\))"
str = "/Date(-31431600000)/"
matches = re.finditer(regex, str)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1
    print ("{match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group())) # -31431600000
```

Answer (score 1):

`r'[^-0-9]'` deletes all characters except `-` and `0-9` digits.

```
[re.sub(r'[^-0-9]','',x) for x in date_list]
```